# The Python 'subprocess' module is much slower than module 'commands' (deprecated)

Tags: python, performance, command, subprocess

I wrote a script that accessed a bunch of servers using [nc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) on the command line, and originally I was using Python's commands module and calling *commands.getoutput()*. The script ran in about 45 seconds. Since *commands* is deprecated, I want to change everything over to using the subprocess module, but now the script takes 2 min 45 secs to run. Why would this be?

What I had before:

```
output = commands.getoutput("echo get file.ext | nc -w 1 server.com port_num")
```

Now I have

```
p = Popen('echo get file.ext | nc -w 1 server.com port_num', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: how long does the command take, when you run from the shell?

Comment: As long as the server doesn't time out, the result is almost instantaneous 

real 0m0.274s
user 0m0.071s
sys 0m0.134s

Comment: do other commands like 'ls', 'uname -a' etc. also take a long time to execute with the subprocess module?

Comment: No, not from what I am seeing. Also when I run the same things (inside the python interpreter) as above, but with time in front, subprocess is actually a bit faster. Not sure why it would be slower once incorporated into my code...

Comment: it seems the problem is not with the subprocess module then...

Comment: Yeah, the only thing that is a little strange is that when I run Popen in the interpreter, it hangs and waits for me to hit enter before returning to the ">>>" prompt

Comment: The real question is why aren't you using the socket module to communicate with the server instead of shelling out to nc?

Comment: @KamilKisiel it's the UNIX way :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would expect `subprocess` to be slower than `command`. Without meaning to suggest that this is the *only* reason your script is running slowly, you should take a look at the [`commands`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/477508efe4ab/Lib/commands.py) source code. There are fewer than 100 lines, and most of the work is delegated to functions from `os`, many of which are taken straight from C [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) libraries (at least in POSIX systems). Note that `commands` is Unix-only, so it doesn't have to do any extra work to ensure cross-platform compatibility.

Now take a look at [`subprocess`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/477508efe4ab/Lib/subprocess.py). There are more than 1500 lines, all pure Python, doing all sorts of checks to ensure consistent cross-platform behavior. Based on this, I would expect `subprocess` to run slower than `commands`.

I timed the two modules, and on something quite basic, `subprocess` was almost twice as slow as `commands`.

```
>>> %timeit commands.getoutput('echo "foo" | cat')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.02 ms per loop
>>> %timeit subprocess.check_output('echo "foo" | cat', shell=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.76 ms per loop
```

[Swiss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10889406/577088) suggests some good improvements that will help your script's performance. But even after applying them, note that `subprocess` is *still* slower.

```
>>> %timeit commands.getoutput('echo "foo" | cat')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.97 ms per loop
>>> %timeit Popen('cat', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate('foo')[0]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.15 ms per loop
```

Assuming you are performing the above command many times in a row, this will add up, and account for at least some of the performance difference.

In any case, I am interpreting your question as being about the relative performance of `subprocess` and `command`, rather than being about how to speed up your script. For the latter question, [Swiss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888846/the-python-subprocess-module-is-much-slower-than-module-commands-deprecated/10889406#10889406) is better.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'm glad I'm not just going crazy. I'm on python 2.6 so I don't even have the option of using check_output.

Comment: I suspect this is not actually the problem here.

Comment: @Swiss, I agree that not using the shell would be better. I guess I was assuming that user1436110 was doing so out of necessity, and answered accordingly. Looking more closely, I see that that's probably not the case. But even after applying the improvements you suggest, `subprocess` is slower. See the new timings above.

Comment: @senderle: It may be true that subprocess is slower. However, a difference of 1 or 2 ms is extremely minor, and does not account for the 2+ minute difference the original question mentions.

Comment: @user1436110, just to clarify: are you downloading large files? About what size? And are you calling `Popen` multiple times in your script? Is the runtime you mention in the comments the runtime for one call to `nc` or many?

Answer (score 21):

There seems to be at least two separate issues here.

First, you are improperly using Popen. Here are the problems I see:

1. Spawning multiple processes with one Popen.
2. Passing one string in as args instead of splitting args.
3. Using the shell to pass text to process rather than the builtin communicate method.
4. Using shell rather than directly spawning processes.

Here is a corrected version of your code

```
from subprocess import PIPE

args = ['nc', '-w', '1', 'server.com', 'port_num']
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate("get file.ext")
print output[0]
```

Second, the fact that you suggest it ends faster when manually run than when run through subprocess suggests that the issue here is that you are not passing the correct string to `nc`. What is probably happening is that the server is waiting for a terminating string to end the connection. If you are not passing this, then the connection probably remains open until it times out.

Run `nc` manually, figure out what the terminating string is, then update the string passed to `communicate`. With these changes it should run much faster.

Comment: Is there a reason for 2? Why is the string version deemed inefficient?

Comment: Hi @Mooncrater, I'm not the OP but I believe the recommendation for 2) is because you want to avoid using Shell=True. So you need to add the command as a list, rather than string.

Comment: Perhaps see also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)