# run os.system command as subprocess python

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I want to run the following **os.system** command as a subprocess in order to know its pid since I want to be able to perform a

```
proc.terminate()
```

Bellow is the `os.system()` Command that works. Note that the bellow command already opens a subshell since thats what the `setview` is doing, and then executes a python script inside that subshell and then exits that subshell.

```
   os.system("/usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview -exec '/usr/bin/python /home/testUser/Development/Scripts/setDoneFlag_Count_Lines.py' testUser__project_5_0_myProject_001")
```

I tried

```
import subprocess
cmd = "/usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview -exec '/usr/bin/python /home/testUser/Development/Scripts/setDoneFlag_Count_Lines.py' testUser__project_5_0_myProject_001"
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), shell=True)
```

Taken from this stackoverflow thread: [How to determine pid of process started via os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218570/how-to-determine-pid-of-process-started-via-os-system)
 But it only executes the first `/usr/atria/bin/cleartool` and not the other commands. Anyone knows how to write a subshell that is equivalent to my os.system call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989922/opening-a-process-with-popen-and-getting-the-pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.split` is not doing you any favors here, because you have spaces within quotes that you don't want to split on. Either pass a string directly, and let the shell handle argument separation:

```
cmd = "/usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview -exec '/usr/bin/python /home/testUser/Development/Scripts/setDoneFlag_Count_Lines.py' testUser__project_5_0_myProject_001"
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Or separate the command manually:

```
cmd = [
    "/usr/atria/bin/cleartool",
    "setview",
    "-exec",
    # single quotes in the argument no longer required, as we're not going through the shell
    "/usr/bin/python /home/testUser/Development/Scripts/setDoneFlag_Count_Lines.py",  
    "testUser__project_5_0_myProject_001"
]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Comment: @anders: `shlex.split()` could be used to get the list. You don't need `shell=True` here.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you splitting your command? Don't use cmd.split(). Try this:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "/usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview -exec '/usr/bin/python /home/testUser/Development/Scripts/setDoneFlag_Count_Lines.py' testUser__project_5_0_myProject_001"
p=subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

Comment: This will try to run the executable called `/usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview...`, ie all the arguments will be treated as part of the executable name