# Python subprocess module does not run script correctly

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm, subprocess

I found this interesting solution for executing python script within another python script, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218672/1227860). I am having difficulty using the module as it does not run the script correctly.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'test.py', ''], shell=True)
print(proc.pid)
```

Content of **`test.py`:**

```
print("I am inside test.py")
```

I am expecting to see the print output `I am inside test.py` but nothing gets printed although I see that `Popen` returns a pid. I am not sure if it has something to do with PyCharm under Ubuntu. I tried this under Windows and I still have the same issue: `I am inside test.py` will not be printed.

Could someone kindly help me out?